# MATLAB cell array and array - error

Tags: matlab

I'd like to understand why the following code works:

```
close all
clear all
t=[0:0.1:10];
x=figure(1);
plot(t,t.^2)
a=getframe(gcf);
b{1}=frame2im(a);
```

instead the following code does not work:

```
close all
clear all
t=[0:0.1:10];
x=figure(1);
plot(t,t.^2)
a=getframe(gcf);
b(1)=frame2im(a);
```

If I use "b(1)=x;" it works.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an array, you can store only *one* 1x1 value of any class at a single index but the class of all elements of an array must be same. In a cell array, there is no such restriction.

`frame2im(a)` is  `[525x700x3 uint8]` and hence you can store it in a cell and not in a simple array if you want to store it at a single index.
`b(1)=x;` works because `x` is `1x1 matlab.ui.Figure`. You can also store `x` in a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you need to know what cells are meant for in MATLAB. If you happen to know Python, you probably will think in a "list"-type way. MATLAB cell can store numbers, strings, etc. However its array is meant to store numbers.
That's why your structure from fram2im can't work.